# Volume element if given metric tensor in spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry

Given the spatial part of the metric tensor
$$g^{\mu\nu} =\begin{bmatrix}
 g^{rr}&0&0\\ 
 0&r^{2}&0\\ 
 0&0&r^{2}sin^2 \theta  
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$
What would be the spherical volume element in this case?
(for example the volume element that observer residing in the center of gravity measures). Obviously in spatially flat case it would be
$$dV=r^2 \sin(\theta)d\theta \, d\phi \, dr$$

In case of the metric (1) would it be correct to write
$$dV=\sqrt{g^{rr}}r^2 \sin(\theta)d\theta \, d\phi \, dr$$

Comment: Do you mean $\color{blue}{\sin^2\theta}$ instead of $\color{blue}{\sin\theta^2}$ in the matrix ?

Comment: Volume element $dV=\sqrt {\det \left( G\right) }drd\varphi d\theta $

Comment: More generally, for an arbitrary spacelike 3-surface: $dV = \sqrt{\left|det g\right|}n^{a}\epsilon_{abcd}dx^{b}dx^{c}dx^{d}$, where $n^{a}$ is the timelike normal to the 3-surface.

Comment: check General relativity: an introduction for physicists from M. P. Hobson, G. P. Efstathiou, A. N. Lasenby.
Manifolds and coordinates => Lengths, areas and volumes

Comment: Those are general formulas, but what about this specific case? Did I write the result correctly (yes or no)

Comment: @Paradoxy: general relativity?

Comment: @CinaedSimson most of elementary books for GR like Hobson or Schutz have some sections for introducing mathematical details in easy way like what is asked here.

Comment: @Eddward Your answer is correct, but you may or may not need a minus sign inside of square root. Depending on $g^{rr}$ sign. For example if you set $g^{rr}=1$ you will recover the volume element of simple spherical coordinate. Which is right: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321781/how-is-the-spherical-coordinate-metric-tensor-derived

Comment: @Paradoxy. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is not correct unless you place the indices downstairs -- $g^{\mu\nu}$ is standard notation for the *inverse* metric, $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\rho}=\delta^{\mu}_{\phantom{a}\rho}$. (if i was marking and saw this in a solution sheet I would definitely mark it as wrong.)